# Mozilla firefox stopped opening any options that require a new window

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm using a 5,1 Macbook and Firefox used to be my main browser.
Out of no where it stopped opening the downloads nor the bookmarks windows. I didn't do anything and neither have I fiddled with about:config.

I tried everything (resetting it or disabling add-ons)

What do you think? Shall I adapt to Chrome or is there any solution to all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the browser will not fix your Firefox problem.

In Firefox, the profiles will sometime become corrupted and introduce weird behavior including certain web pages not loading correctly. Your problem however, is something I have never seen before.

You may want to try creating a new profile to isolate the error. If the issue is indeed within the profile, Mozilla offers a sync service (Firefox 10+ I think) that can be used to store your bookmarks and such, and later sync to the new profile.

You could also try upgrading to a newer version, or downgrading to an older version if your profile has plugin configurations and user settings that you would rather not reset.

Comment: I've their latest version (16.0.2) and I installed the 16 and 15 but without any result.
And about the syncing, I'm not really worried (xmarks & lastpass) are all I need. I'm not sure though how to create a new profile. Wouldn't resetting it create a new one by default?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by resetting a profile. A new profile can be created with the built-in profile manager. Run firefox -ProfileManager.

Comment: I meant: I thought resetting Firefox will delete my old profile and create a new one. Anyhow, I didn't know about this handy Profile Manager. I launched it and created a new one and voila it's working again! Thanks brother!

Comment: You're welcome. This happens when plugins fail to clean up after themselves properly (or when upgrading) more often than when Mozilla makes some mistake.

Comment: Now here's a super funny thing/bug/glitch; I'm using a secondary monitor, if firefox was on the main monitor the bookmarks or the downloads windows would open, if the window was on the secondary monitor, it WON'T! How cool is that?

Comment: Forget that dialog... Check out the "download statusbar" addon and enable mini-mode.